# The correct way to access sub resources in REST service

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Let's imagine we have a resource As that contains Bs which in it's turn contains Cs.

To get all the Cs I'd usually create controller method with URL like **As/Bs/Cs**. And to get a particular B I would do **As/Bs/{bId}**. But is this correct ?

How someone else would understand that this "Cs" part in the first URL is the name of the sub resource, not the {bId} ? Specially if B has a string id.

Shouldn't it be something like a wildcard symbol, that would make the first query look like **As/*/Bs/*/Cs**, So you would immediately see what is id and what is the sub resource ?

Comment: Could you please provide a _real world example_? IMHO `A`, `B` and `C` are _too abstract_ to provide you a _concrete answer_.

Comment: Sure. For example: we have servers, they has deployments and deployments has executions. And all these resources has strings as ids.
Usually to get executions client would do something like servers/deployments/executions, and to get particular deployment he would do servers/deployments/{dId} But how he can be sure that server side will treat "executions" part as the resource name, not as {dId}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

When a URL matches multiple patterns, a sort is used to find the most specific match. How is it determined? A pattern with a lower count of URI variables and wild cards is considered more specific.

So `/servers/deployments/executions` is more specific than `/servers/deployments/{deploymentId}`.

### A bit longer answer

The Spring MVC documentation tells you the whole story:

> [**Path Pattern Comparison**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison)
>
> When a URL matches multiple patterns, a sort is used to find the most specific match.
>
> A pattern with a lower count of URI variables and wild cards is considered more specific. For example `/hotels/{hotel}/*` has 1 URI variable and 1 wild card and is considered more specific than `/hotels/{hotel}/**` which as 1 URI variable and 2 wild cards.
>
> If two patterns have the same count, the one that is longer is considered more specific. For example `/foo/bar*` is longer and considered more specific than `/foo/*`.
>
> When two patterns have the same count and length, the pattern with fewer wild cards is considered more specific. For example `/hotels/{hotel}` is more specific than `/hotels/*`.
>
> There are also some additional special rules:
>
> - The default mapping pattern `/**` is less specific than any other pattern. For example `/api/{a}/{b}/{c}` is more specific.
> - A prefix pattern such as `/public/**` is less specific than any other pattern that doesn’t contain double wildcards. For example `/public/path3/{a}/{b}/{c}` is more specific.